# AForge.NET Recursive Layer

Tags: neural-network, aforge

I'm reading Neural Network Design by Hagan, Demuth, Beale and De Jesús, and trying to implement simple networks in C# (using AForge.NET).

They describe both Hamming and Hopfield Networks, that use a recursive layer to elaborate inputs.

Is there an implementation of this layer/network type in AForge.NET?

As far as I understand it, implementing it myself would also require to write custom learning classes to support recursion.